# Making prayer on behalf of someone I care for who doesn't read namaaz

Tags: salat, practical-islam

So let's just say that I want to pray fajr namaaz for someone I care for who doesn't read namaaz. If I read 2 farz namaaz on behalf of this person, would the Salah be accepted for the person or is there no point of praying Salah on behalf of another person?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the person is still alive. In this case it is not possible for you to discharge the obligation of Salah on their behalf, if you do so it will still remain due on them.

> ### وأن ليس للإنسان إلا ما سعى
>
> And that there is not for man except that for which he strives
>
> <sup>— [Quran 53:39](http://quran.com/53/39)</sup>
>
> وأجمعوا أن لا يصلي أحد عن أحد
>
> And there is consensus that no one can pray on behalf of someone else
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura53-aya39.html#qortobi)</sup>

> #### لا يصوم أحد عن أحد ولا يصلي أحد عن أحد
>
> No one can fast or do the prayer for anyone else
>
> <sup>—[Muwatta Malik](https://sunnah.com/urn/506742)</sup>

Comment: Can someone do Hajj on the behalf of someone who has died? I heard It's a thing allowed in the Hanafi Fiqh. Is it?

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan Comments are for clarifications on the answer, not for asking tangential questions. Generally performing Hajj on behalf of a deceased is at least permissible according to not just the Hanafis but also other schools of thought. The Shafi'is and Hanbalis consider it to be obligatory to do so if it was obligatory on the deceased. And the Hanafis and Malikis consider it permissible. There are ahadith on that such as: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1852

Comment: I understand now, may Allah bless you for answering.